# Can't change Windows SDK version in Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual Studio C++ console application that I created with Visual Studio 2015 and now I can't compile it (with Visual Studio 2017) because it is targeting the Windows 8.1 SDK, which is not installed. The problem is that I can't retarget the project to the Windows 10 SDK.

What happens is that when I open the project properties page and go to *General - Target Platform* I see the Windows 10 SDK in the dropdown, and I am able to select it... but as soon as I press *Apply*, **it reverts back to 8.1 by itself**. No error message is provided.

[image]

Visual Studio installer says that, indeed, the listed SDK version is installed:

[image]

So what's going on here? Is there a way to retarget my project without having to install the Windows 8.1 SDK?

*Not sure if that matters but: this project is actually just a "wrapper" around an existing bare project consisting of just a bunch of .cpp and .h files, which was developed by another person. I'm really not familiar with C++ development.*

Comment: simply install the 8.1 SDK to avoid changing the SDK version

Answer (score 7):

After hours of struggling with this problem, I coincidentally discovered that **selecting Project Properties/General, changing "Platform Toolset" to v141_xp** (instead of v141) forcibly drops the Windows SDK Version to 8.1 or 7.0. I'm not sure how Visual Studio chooses which SDK to use.

EDIT: You must edit .vcxproj and change both:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17134.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17134.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
```

Comment: Tried this and it still reverts back with vs 2019

Comment: It's a mess, IDK how to help sorry.

Comment: I ended up just giving in and installing the SDK version the project was locked onto, luckily it didn't break anything important