# C++ Reading from a serial port with CreateFile

Tags: c++, sdk, serial-port, visual-studio-2017, createfile

I am writing a C++ program to read from a serial port (in my case COM6). To open the COM-Port. I always found this code in the internet:

```
HANDLE serialHandle;

serialHandle = CreateFile(L"COM6", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

My Problem is that I get the following errors:

- 'HANDLE': identifier not found
- 'CreateFile': identifier not found
- 'GENERIC_READ': undeclared identifier
- 'INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE': undeclared identifier
- ...

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    /*int comPortNmr = 6, speed = 115200;
    cout << "Serial Line: > ";
    cin >> comPortNmr;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Speed: > ";
    cin >> speed;
    cout << endl; */

    HANDLE serialHandle;
    // Open serial port
    serialHandle = CreateFile(L"COM6", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

    if (serialHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "Error." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Opend." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could not reproduce. What IDE / compiler are you using? Do you have the appropriate Windows SDK installed?

Comment: I am using the default Visual Studio 2017 IDE / Compiler. I haven't changed anything in the settings.

Comment: @User987123 If you install VS'17 without adjusting the settings, the Windows SDK will NOT install. Please adjust your settings and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using precompiled headers, anything up to and including the line `#include "stdafx.h"` is supposed to already be part of the precompiled header. And so will be skipped by the compiler.

So make sure that `#include "stdafx.h"` always is the **first** `#include`.

Answer (score 3):

If you install VS'17 without adjusting the settings, the Windows SDK will NOT install.

Please re-check your VS'17 installation and install the appropiate Windows SDK.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325182/cant-change-windows-sdk-version-in-visual-studio-c-project Has a little screenshot of some Windows SDKs.

Comment: I am using Windows7 but in the Visual Studio Installer I only can install SDK's for Windows 10. What should I do now?

Comment: @User987123 Install the latest 10 or 8.1. Currently unable to tell exactly which one you need. It will work on Windows 7.

Comment: I have installed the SDK's and in the project settings I changed it to the new SDK version but it is still not working.