# I can't change Windows SDK Version to 10.0.17763.0 , it just resets back to 8.1 when I click apply

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to compile mpc-hc. I get many errors like `cannot open include file "ctype.h"` and such, and headers visual studio used were from 8.1 sdk. I deleted every sdk but the lastest one, but now I'm getting this:

`The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution"`

But I can't tell visual studio to use the lastest sdk. It just resets back to sdk 8.1 immediately.

I tried this [Can't change Windows SDK version in Visual Studio C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325182/cant-change-windows-sdk-version-in-visual-studio-c-project) , the 10.0.17763.0 is now set, but in the gui there is still 8.1 displayed.

I also tried deleting some settings in visual studio as described here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/ , but I didn't get where to run the `devenv /resetuserdata` command.

Okay, so I just added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt` in the `Include Directories`, and it seems to work. Now I have to add this to every project I have, manually.

Comment: post your steps as answer and don't add it to your question

Comment: instead of using a fixed SDK then you could use $(LatestTargetPlatformVersion)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, only for mpc-be: there's a file called platform.props which looks for an env. var. called $(MPCBE_WINSDK_VER) and if it cannot find it, it'll set the WindowsTargetPlatformVersion element to 8.1. Change this '8.1' to any other version you'd prefer (like '10.0').